# Timing a circuit's 'on-cycle' after a push button switch is pressed

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, microchip, timing

First off, thank you for reading all of this - you are the part of the internet that gives me hope for mankind. I’m looking for a circuit that I would think is relatively straightforward, but has a few important nuances.

The end goal is to turn on a user to have the ability to hit a push button switch, which sends power an electromagnet. The electromagnet will be on for a period of one hour. I would like to be able to easily switch the design to two hours, but the PCB itself will have a single predetermined time period.

After the hour is up, the electromagnet turns off and stays off until the next button press.

- During it’s ‘off’ phase, I need minimum power drain – I would like a long shelf life
- The circuit is being run off of 2 AA batteries. With the batteries hooked up directly to the electromagnet, the 3v results in approximately 30ma is being drawn from the electromagnet, scaling down as the batteries drain (alkaline batteries).
- A cheap solution is necessary – this is going into a product with pretty low margins. Hoping for less than $2 for the PCB fabrication & assembly.
- If anything goes wrong (eg soldering crack, etc) it is important that the electromagnet is off.

Thus far, we have been experimenting with the TI5111 nanotimer in ‘one-shot’ mode. http://www.ti.com/product/TPL5111. We have ran into a few hiccups using this (eg voltage drop of npn transistor)

I'm looking into micro controllers, such as https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC10F200#additional-features but the datasheet blows my mind.

I'm basically just looking for something I can put between the batteries and electromagnet that results in a button press allowing the 3V to go through to the electromagnet, then shutting it off after an hour or two.

oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

on a side note:

I've had a lot of people comment on the amount of button presses given I'm only using 2 AA. The electromagnet can hold what I need as long as the current is above 15ma. I'm purposefully drawing 30ma to begin, knowing that the alkaline batteries I'm using will lose voltage as they are used. Based on spec sheets, I expect 2500maH before the voltage drops from 1.5v per battery to .8, which would cut my current from 30ma to right around 15ma. Given this logic, and drawing around 25ma on average, I would expect around 100 hours of 'on-time'. I only need this to last 60ish hours, so I'm good on that aspect.

But if there is a large significant voltage drop between the batteries and electromagnet due to the timing solution, I can get into some trouble because there isn't a ton of room for the voltage to decay. Eg we used a npn transistor with the ti5111 timer and it resulted in a .7V drop between drain and source (we are trying to work around this), so my electromagnet was only receiving 2.3V on a 3V battery, which would drop the number of uses significantly as the batteries drained. 
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Any suggestions on whether you would use a microcontroller or something like the TI5111 timer? I'm not an engineer, so this is all new to me. We are looking to implement this in a consumer product, so the less than $2 per for the electronics is on a relatively large order (1000-5000).

Any help is very much appreciated - let me know if you have any questions!!

Comment: TI5111 is bad choice since it is designed to drive logic input. What you need is TI5110, designed for P-FET. Everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: We initially were using the TI5110 with a p channel transistor, but if something was soldered incorrectly we thought there was risk that it would stay on past the allotted time - which is why we switched to the 5111. Could we make a failsafe design with the 5110?

Comment: Sorry, that does not make any sense. If something soldered incorrectly you can for example short-circuit the battery, regardless of what chip you are using. The behavior of both chips is exactly the same, so the imagined "risk" is also identical. And I hope you mean p-channel MOSFET, not PNP BJT. Also, if this is supposed to be mass-production then "soldered incorrectly" sounds _really_ strange. That's what quality control is for.

Comment: You can do this with a 20 cent CMOS Clock /binary counter with a power Logic level FET (Vt<1V) delay outputs are clk /2^N next output goes to disable with inverter. Button controls Reset.

Comment: `We have ran into a few hiccups using this (eg voltage drop of npn transistor)` .... you will run into the same "hiccups" with almost any chip that you decide to use ... the issue is with using a correct driver circuit to interface a digital output to an electromagnet

Comment: You could also consider a 555 timer.  With low power high frequency ones you can operate at fairly low voltages and with a fairly small timing cap.  A mosfet will probably greatly improve your efficiency and you could also use a mosfet driver with it for faster switching or to drive a mosfet from a logic level output.

Comment: @KH I don't think any 555 timer can come even close to 35 nA of TPL5110

Comment: @Maple that is true.  That's a nice little chip.  Am I understanding correctly that it has a built in mosfet driver?

Comment: Yes, it has p-fet driver. The companion TPL5111 chip has logic high output for controlling EN pins of DC-DC or LDO. There are other chips in that line with watchdog function, also with gate driver option.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying this breakout board for TPL5110 with a FET and potentiometer integrated into it? FET should have very little voltage drop and breakout board can prove solution before integrating parts four lower cost. https://www.adafruit.com/product/3435

Comment: Yes, that board has correct chip. The only problem - it has mode of operation hardwired for timer. In order to use it for one-shot you have to hack the trace to EN pin.

Comment: That's ok, hack it with an exacto knife for proof of concept,  then implement it tailored to your use-case once you prove it works in your application. There is a trace designed to be cut on the back of the breakout to make it easy.

Comment: following up on this, commenting on @maple 's comment above. When we hand soldered this piece onto a PCB, we found that it was staying on past the allotted time - indefinitely. We had an EE review the circuit, and he said that it looked good to him so he thought it must be a soldering issue.

The 'worst-case' scenario in this project is that it stays on past the allotted time. I know that when we do a production run, it would be machine soldered - but even if we tested each of them after production, is there a chance something could happen post testing that would keep it in the on state?

Comment: "Intrinsically Safe" design is a topic unto itself... components can always fail, solder joints can fail,  not in scope for this question

Comment: @SteveButler How exactly replacing perfectly suitable component with the one not so suitable but with same pinout, package and logic helps you avoid that hypothetical failure scenario?! It's like "if we do not tighten nuts properly the wheel can come off the car. Let's replace those nuts with plastic ones"

Comment: It’s just when we think about it logically, pin 5 is always high on the 5110 except for the hour duration (when it goes to low). Since pin 5 is high, there is no current going through the p-channel transistor when it's 'off'. If anything happened to the 5110 timer causing it to fail, the p-channel transistor would allow the current to flow though to the electromagnet.

Comment: We thought the 5111 would work better because the default on pin 5 is low. Pin 5 is high during the hour duration. With an n-channel transistor, current through will only flow through if pin 5 is high. So in this case, if the 5111 breaks – the n-channel transistor wouldn’t allow any current through.

Comment: I'm sure I sound like a complete idiot and half that shit may not make sense so I apologize - I'm trying to understand this but I've been struggling to wrap my head around it

Comment: You keep saying "transistor". Technically MOSFETs are transistors, but it is so confusing... Anyway, have you actually _tried_ to connect just source and drain of P-FET and _see_ if the current would flow?

Comment: I apologize - maybe it'll help if I link the stuff I'm talking about. So with the 5110, we were using https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=BSS84PH6433XTMA1CT-ND. And it worked, but we were just worried that if anything happened to the chip causing no current to flow through it - the electromagnet would always be on (which is our worst-case scenario)

Comment: I recommend reading on a difference between "enhancement-mode" and "depletion-mode" MOSFETs. It will all become clear.

Comment: So then we tried the 5111 with this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/BSS138NH6433XTMA1/BSS138NH6433XTMA1CT-ND/ and it nearly worked as well, but we saw the voltage drop to 2.3V going to the electromagnet

Answer (score 0):

A different solution: Can you engineer something like a *Vacuum Time Lag Switch?*  You push the button on the switch, expels all air, and then a spring return acts against the switch with a small hole allowing air slowly back into the system.  I know the wall mounted ones like shown below work for about 10 min but you might be able to run with the idea.

[image: Vacuum Time Lag Switch]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a circuit using a 555 timer
[image: timer]

You can increase or decrease the on time by turning the potentiometer (pot 200k), in case that is not enough you can also increase the value of the pot along with the value of the resistor in series with it to achieve higher on time. The higher the resistor and pot value,the longer the on time. Also the lower the value, the shorter the on time.

I use a relay on the output, in case you want to connect it with your load you will need to remove the relay and place your load in place of the relay.